# Cocos2d 3.2 SD resources loading where -hd should be

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

game near finished in 3.2 and i realized that my retina assets arent being used. i did not use spritebuilder. i have "-hd" and "" suffixed assets. here is how i load these files (PVR.CCZs)

```
//resources loaded
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"menu.plist"];


//sprite call
CCSprite * background =[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"main_art_back.png"];
```

on 5s and 6 devices, it loads the non-retina assets. i have been working my layouts using these and i just realized the issue. i erased all assets and just loaded all the HD assets without any suffix (i.e. "") and in 5s, everything renders 2x if it wasn't scaled. very confusing. see screenshot. basically, why are my -hd assets not loading on retina devices? am i missing some point to pixel conversion? is this from not using spritebuilder?

[image: screenshot]

i cross posted as i feel like someone on forums.cocos2d-swift.org should help but i usually get responses that are much more helpful on stackoverflow!